# Why are the message formats different in Mathematica and Wolfram Player?

Tags: wolfram-player

I wrote Manipulate and compared the results of the message in Mathematica and Wolfram Player.

```
Manipulate[ToExpression@in,
Style[Control@{{in, Null}, InputField[#, Boxes] &, ImageSize -> {400, 50}}, 20]]
```

[image]

As shown in the figure above, the output form of the error message is different in Mathematica and Wolfram Player.

Question 1. Can't Wolfram Player output a message in the form of Mathematica?

Question 2. If that is not possible, can you set the width of the message output cell to express the sentence without line change?